# How to open "Sign-in with your Google account" page like present model View when I press "Sign in with Google"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

In my current app, I am using "Sign-in with Google". I always want to open that "Sign-in with your Google account" page in type present model ViewController even if I installed google apps like "Google+ ".

But now what's happening in my app is if I already sign into Google+ app, which is already installed, it is opening that app instead of "Sign-in with Google" page. This means that it's coming from out of my app and opening the Google+ app. I don't want that.

Here is my code:

```
GIDSignIn *signIn = [GIDSignIn sharedInstance];
signIn.clientID = kClientId;
signIn.allowsSignInWithBrowser = YES;
signIn.scopes = @[@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"];
signIn.delegate = self;
[signIn signIn];
```

My app goal is every time I need to open "Sign-in with Google" page rather than Google apps when I click on "Sign in with Google" button.

Answer (score 0):

I have a project using Google Signin Integration with the same problem.
First, you need to know clearly about how Google Signin SDK working.
You can see the reference from **Ian Barber** here: [Login through google plus to native app does not shows login page every time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629899/login-through-google-plus-to-native-app-does-not-shows-login-page-every-time)

So here is my solution:

Every times I open the login view, after setting Google Signin configurations in ViewDidLoad, I call function "[signin logout]" to log out the current user.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Configure Google Signin
    GIDSignIn *signin = [GIDSignIn sharedInstance];
    //Sign out
    [signin signOut];
    signin.delegate = self;
    signin.uiDelegate = self;
}
```

Hope this will be helpful for you!

Answer (score 0):

In my project, there are google sign in and I have used latest `GIDSignInButton` to login. I follow all steps from [Integrating Google Sign-In into your iOS app](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in). And checked it is successful login. The problem in it is I have to use Google's `GIDSignInButton` to login which is not fit in my app's UI.

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet GIDSignInButton *googleSigninbtn;
```

So I have taken my own button, and hide `GIDSignInButton` from my storyboard. I have made IBOutlet of `GIDSignInButton` already. Now on click of my own button I have used this outlet to call its delegate methods.

```
- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender
{
    [self.googleSigninbtn sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

As this button is hidden but it is in storyboard, so it works and I can login with google from my app. It works.