# initiate Google Signin without the GIDSignInButton but programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa, google-signin

Is there a way to launch the Google SignIn programmatically without pressing on the GIDSignInButton ?

I'm trying to wrap a signal around hitting google api where the user must log in.

sort of :

```
googleSignInSignal().then(getPersonalDataSignal)
```

Answer (score 20):

You can actually call this method instead:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
```

It worked fine for me and it seems to be a much cleaner approach.

I hope it can help someone with the same question.

Comment: Pretty old, but don't forget to set `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().presentingViewController = instanceOfYourViewController` before calling this method.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this - not pretty, but works:

```
GIDSignInButton *googleButton  =[[GIDSignInButton alloc] init];
[googleButton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have answered on [answer to same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30034365/how-to-open-sign-in-with-your-google-account-page-like-present-model-view-when/32503153#32503153) and it works for me. I have follewed all steps and created outlet of signing button as

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet GIDSignInButton *googleSigninbtn;
```

and use this button  as

```
[self.googleSigninbtn sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I have hide this button from storyboard and add this code in my own button's action and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was calling GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn() but Google's canned WebView for OAuth was not showing up after the call. Also, the events were not being triggered on the configured GIDSignInUIDelegate or GIDSignInDelegate objects.

The problem was that in my UIViewController I was calling dismiss() before calling signIn(). Google's UI won't pop up if you already dismissed the view controller.

Answer (score -1):

Eventually I ended up just calling

```
        let signIn = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()
        signIn.delegate = self
        signIn.uiDelegate = uiDelegate

        if silent {
            signIn.signInSilently()
        }
        else {
            signIn.signIn()
        }
```